# Spl_autoload_register failed to open stream

Tags: php, class, include, autoload, spl-autoload-register

This is Server/Init.php:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($file) {
    include str_replace('\\, '/', $file) . '.php';
});

$GLOBALS['config']  = $config;
$GLOBALS['patched'] = $patched;
$GLOBALS['crumbs']  = $crumbs;

$utils = new Utils();
$mysql = new MySQL();
$GLOBALS['utils'] = $utils;
$GLOBALS['mysql'] = $mysql;
```

The problems seem to be with trying to include Utils.php, which is inside the classes folder. These are the errors:

```
Warning: include(Utils.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:/xampp/htdocs/server/Init.php on line 9

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Utils.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:/xampp/php/PEAR') in C:/xampp/htdocs/server/Init.php on line 9

Fatal error: Class 'Utils' not found in C:/xampp/htdocs/server/Init.php on line 16
```

If it helps, this is Server/Classes/Utils.php:

```
class Utils {

    public function writeRawOutput($str) {
        echo $str;
    }

    public function writeOutput($msg, $type = null, $pref = null) {
        $msg = strval($msg);
        if($type == null && $pref == null)
            echo "$msg \r\n";
        elseif($type == null && $pref != null)
            echo "[$pref] > $msg \r\n";
        elseif($type != null && $pref == null)
            echo "[$type] > $msg \r\n";
        elseif($type != null && $pref != null)
            echo "[$pref] [$type] > $msg \r\n";
    }

    public function getInput($str) {
        $this->writeOutput($str);
        $input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        return $input;
    }

    public function getConfig($path = null) {
        if($path) {

            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path   = explode('/', $path);

            foreach($path as $bit) {
                if(isset($config[$bit])) {
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
            }

            return $config;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

What have I done wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: (1) You posted `Init.php` has a syntax error. I assume this is not really the case for the real file. (2) If `Init.php` is in the 'main' directory, and classes can be found in a './classes/' subdir, `include __DIR__.'/classes/'.str_replace('\\', '/', $file) . '.php';`

Comment: Inside the "Server" directory is Init.php and a folder called "Classes" which contains Utils.php.